# How to debug a DLL in Visual Studio that I call from Python using ctypes?

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, debugging, ctypes

I am coding a C++ DLL in Visual Studio that I call from Python using ctypes. Calling the functions and returning the results works just fine. However, I haven't figured out how to debug the C++ code while it's being called from Python. I did the obvious thing, i.e. started debugging the Python code (currently using PyScripter but that's not set in stone), and then attached the VS debugger to the Python process. I also checked the process ID in TaskManager to make sure I attach to the correct process. This seems to work, i.e. VS doesn't complain, the break points in the C++ code remain full red dots (meaning the breakpoints can be hit), and the "Detach..." command in the Debug menu is active. However, when the Python eventually calls one of the C++ functions, the break point is *not* hit. The function returns the correct result, but execution does *not* halt at the break point. Has anybody got experience in this and could help me? Thanks!

Comment: are you sure you compiled your dll with debug symbols (i THINK thats a thing you need to do)?

Comment: I just verified, and yes, I do generate the symbols

Comment: Ensure to select "Native" while attaching. VS attempts to autodetect and attaches as Python debugger instead in newer versions (since 2017 I think).

Comment: Throw an unhandled exception where you want to break.  See if that works :^)  I debug C++ DLLs with Python all the time and what you describe should work.  Esp. if the breakpoint resolves (red dots).  Are optimizations off?  Sometimes code doesn't execute the flow expected if it is optimized.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation page for [mixed-mode debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/python/debugging-mixed-mode-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio) spells it out in detail, but the short version is:

## When you have a Project

Open Project Properties, switch to the Debug tab, and select *Enable native code debugging*. Now when you press F5 you will be in a mode that lets you debug both Python and C/C++ code naturally.

## When you attach to a running process

Before attaching, click the *Select* button to select debugging engines. You will want to select **both** *Native* and *Python* together (by default, it will select only Python if it detects Python in the process).

[image: Screen shot of the Select Code Type dialog from Microsoft's documentation]